# PHP is a class image resizing composition of file handling class?

Tags: php, file, design-patterns, image-processing, file-handling

Im planning to develop a file handling class, which performs nessary file operation , such as moving the file, ensuring the file type and size. And also an ImageResize class which resizes image to a specific width or height , or write watermark on the image.
My question is , Is a Imageresize.php  class composition of FileHandling.php  . Which I mean you cannot perform ImageResize method without creating the object of filehandling.

Comment: In the past I've always kept the two separate.  I suppose you could make a generic file handling abstract class and extend it with your `ImageResize` class.  Also, good luck with image manipulation in PHP, it kinda sucks.

Comment: @JvdBerg I have created seperate classes, but I want it to using a pattern or at least proper OOP design.  Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: @mmmshuddup why keep them seperate, I mean the imageresize can use functions from the filehandling class, and imageresize cannot exist without filehandling , so isnt it composition ?

Comment: @meWantToLearn That's why you could `extend` the `FileHandle` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ImageResize class will need some methods from the FileHandling, and it's likely that you'll need more classes to work on various sections of the files, create the FileHandling as an interface, and let ImageResize class implement it. Other classes that require the FileHandling interface can also implement it when needed.

Comment: Requiring ImageResize to implement file handling operations breaks the Single Responsibility Principle.  This creates extra work because you are implementing file handling operations in many parts of the code.

Comment: That's actually true. I should make adjustment to my answer.